# Hide system UI when ListPreference dialog is up

Tags: java, android

So I have a custom `ListPreference` that I want to hide the `System UI Elements` once the dialog box is presented on the screen.

[image: Before]

I have found a post about how to hide element inside the dialog box itself (like the cancel button and title), however, I am not quite sure on how to access those particular pieces.

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) {
    super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);
    //hide System UI elements here
}
```

This looks like a good place to make the changes to me, however, I am not 100% on it.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

This is how the activities accomplish what I am trying to achieve.
`getView()` is also what I assume to be an approach to this, however, I am not quite sure if the dialog box is a Fragment or not.

Ok so I am able to hide the UI elements but it seem like there is still some sort of transparent bars left over.

[image: After]

**Does anyone know of a way to get rid of these remnant bars?**

```
@Override
protected void showDialog(Bundle state) {
    super.showDialog(state);
    getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```

This is how I am getting rid of the `System UI Elements`.